# Почему в IntellyJ не активнен пункт меню Build - Build artifacts?

Tags: java

Почему в IntellyJ не активнен пункт меню Build - Build artifacts?

Пункт меню не нажимается.

Как сделать его активным?

Answer (score 1):

Предположу, что Вы не настроили то что нужно забилдить. Если не добавлены артефакты в меню File -> Project structure -> Artifacts - добавьте и кнопка должна стать активной.